# find minimum value of $x^4-x$ without using calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

as title, is there a way to find the minimum value of $x^4-x$ without using calculus?

By calculus it's easy as $(x^4-x)'=4x^3-1$, so we got $x=\frac1{\sqrt[3]4}$, then we get the min value. But without calculus, is it possible?

I tried to use AM-GM but to no avail...

Comment: First step: $x$ must be non-negative, because if $x$ is negative then $$(-x)^4-(-x)=x^4+x=x^4-x+2x<x^4-x.$$

Comment: We also easily get the minimum must be $0<x<1,$ since it is negative there, and positive everywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That the minimum is negative and thus the minimizer inside the interval $0<x<1$ was already established.

Use AM-GM in the form $$\sqrt[4]{a^3b}\le\frac{3a+b}4.$$ Setting $3a=1-x^3$ and $b=x^3$ gives the right side as constant $\frac14$ and the left side as $(x(1-x^3)/3)^{3/4}$. Thus the minimum of the function is
$$
-\frac3{4\sqrt[3]4}
$$
at $x^3=(1-x^3)/3$, that is, $$x=\frac1{\sqrt[3]4}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Once you know the minimum must be negative [as $x^4-x=x(x^3-1) <0 $ when $x\in (0, 1)$], it isn't hard to use AM-GM. Let this minimum be $-m$.

$$x^4+m=x^4+3\times\frac13m \geqslant 4\sqrt[4]{x^4m^3/(3^3)}=4\sqrt[4]{\frac{m^3}{3^3}}|x| \geqslant 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{m^3}{27}}x$$
Hence if we select $m$ s.t. $m^3=\frac{27}{4^4}$, we get $x^4-x \geqslant -m$ and hence the minimum.

P.S. *It is simple to see that equality is possible.*

Comment: Can you please tell what formula did you use for getting $$x^4+3\times\frac13m \geqslant 4\sqrt[4]{x^4m^3/(3^3)}$$

Comment: Thats using standard AM-GM with the four terms: $x^4, m/3, m/3, m/3$.  Essentially we split $m$ into three parts so that we can use fourth order AM-GM, thereby reducing the power of $x^4$ to what we want.  $(a+b+c+d)/4\geqslant \sqrt[4]{abcd}$ is the general version of that AM-GM

Comment: Ah okay yeah I missed such an obvious thing. Thanks

Comment: But $-m$ is the minimum , you can’t just select $m^3=\frac{27}{4^4}$, can you?

Comment: @athos Because $-m$ is the minimum of $f(x)=x^4-x$, it must satisfy the equation $f(x)\geqslant -m$ (with equality possible).  Apart from the selected value of $m$, no other value will give this inequality (with equality possible).  Hence the selection is perfectly fine, in fact you cannot select anything else.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it!